# Execute batch file every X runs

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file I want to run at Windows shutdown (executed via GPO shutdown script) but I only want it to run after a certain number of system shutdowns, not at every shutdown. This is because what it does causes a delay in the shutdown process and I want to reduce disruption.

The only thing I can think about is to construct some logic that checks how many times the computer was shut down and after the defined threshold is crossed the batch file is executed, but would anyone have an example of how to do this? I searched but only found examples of how to run a script every x periods or times, not every x runs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a counter stored in a file then read and update it each time the batch file is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SET LIMIT=4
SET SAVEFILE="COUNT.TXT"
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

REM Get the current count or start a new file if it does not exist.
IF EXIST %SAVEFILE% GOTO READFILE
ECHO 0 >%SAVEFILE%
:READFILE
SET /P COUNT= <%SAVEFILE%

REM Increment the save file value by one.
FOR %%B IN ( "%SAVEFILE%" ) DO (
  CALL :ADD_ONE
)
ECHO %COUNT% >%SAVEFILE%
GOTO CHECK_VALUE
:ADD_ONE
SET /A COUNT+=1
GOTO :EOF

REM Conditionally reset the counter and do something.
:CHECK_VALUE
IF %COUNT% LSS %LIMIT% EXIT /B
DEL %SAVEFILE% 2>NUL

ECHO Do your stuff here...
```

Comment: Thanks again - will check and report back!

Answer (score 1):

You could call your batch file upon every shutdown, and include the following at the top to abort if the shutdown threshold has not been met.

```
@echo off

::Test if the shutdown threshold has been met. Exit if it hasn't
setlocal
set /a "threshold=5, cnt=1"
set shutdownCountFile="C:\SomePath\shutdownCount.txt"
if exist %shutdownCountFile% for /f "usebackq" %%A in (%shutdownCountFile%) do set /a cnt=%%A+1
if %cnt% geq %threshold% (
  2>nul del %shutdownCountFile%
  endlocal
) else (
  >%shutdownCountFile% echo %cnt%
  exit /b
)

:: Your batch process goes here
```

You could also use a registry entry to keep track of the number of shutdowns instead of a file.

Comment: That looks great! Thank you so much for the prompt and helpful reply - much appreciated :) Will test asap and report back ;)

Comment: Windows XP --> "usebackq" was unexpected at this time.

Comment: OK I tested this and I think I don't understand what needs to be in the shutdownCount.txt file? This is what I'm getting:

    C:\Users\Erez\Desktop>1.bat

    C:\Users\Erez\Desktop>setlocal

    C:\Users\Erez\Desktop>set /a "threshold=5, cnt=1"

    C:\Users\Erez\Desktop>set shutdownCountFile="C:\Users\Erez\Desktop\shutdownCount.txt"
    "usebackq" was unexpected at this time.

    C:\Users\Erez\Desktop>for %F "usebackq" %A in ("C:\Users\Erez\Desktop\shutdownCount.txt") do set /a cnt=%A+1

    C:\Users\Erez\Desktop>

Comment: @user1630260 - Oops, I had a typo. I used `FOR %%F` when I meant to type `FOR /F`. I also had an unintended error message popping up. All fixed now.